# git commit nolonger showing up in log

Tags: git, git-log, git-checkout

Yesterday I git-commited, then checked out multiple old commits and also used `stash` on some of them.

Now yesterday's commit is no longer showing up in `git log`.

I dont know the tree-ish but i know the exact comment i used.

I tried checking out the most-recent before yesterday's commit but it still does not show up in the log-tree.

Is there some way to checkout or search by the comment i gave it? (Also is there a reason why it nolonger shows up in `git log`?)

Comment: Were the commits, you are not able to find, were pushed to remote or were local commits?

Comment: @saurabh This is solved. See edvinas.me's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reflog` locally so you can see the history of what you did (when the tips of the branches were updated):

```
$ git reflog
```

It will also show you the commit hashes so you should be able to find the commit you are looking for and checkout to it or merge it depending on what was done.